# Logical expression using colon and braces

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm having trouble understanding how this piece of code works using the underscore library. I see a piece of code as follows:

`const ent = _.find(m.ents, { ent: r.ent });`

I know that the second argument of a _.find is a predicate but I'm not quite sure how the { ent: r.ent } becomes a predicate in javascript.

Comment: This would be easier with es6 syntax instead of underscore.

Comment: Hi, this is a very weird code example, what I can say is that in js `{key: value}` is an object (or associative array) with one element, the element can be accessed with the key `key` and has the value `value`. `key` type can be either a `string` or an `integer`, and `value` can be any type supported by js. You can access your element value using the notation `obj.key` or `obj['key']` the two expressions return `value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
_.find(m.ents, { ent: r.ent });
```

is equivalent to:

```
m.ents.find((x) => x.ent === r.ent );
```

AsJimmy noted in the comments above, I, too, find ES6 syntax clearer than underscore. But I guess it's easier to use underscore when you have multiple conditions (comparing multiple attributes) for example:

```
_.find(m.ents, { ent: r.ent, a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
```

is less verbose than:

```
m.ents.find((x) => x.ent === r.ent && x.a === r.a && x.b === r.b && x.c === r.c);
```